# How to create a deep frozen version of an object without mutating the original?

Tags: javascript, object, immutability

Let's say we have the following object:

```js
"use strict"; // To trigger errors on frozen objects mutation attempts

const myObj = {
  rootProp1: {
    leafProp1: "hello",
    leafProp2: "world",
  rootProp2: "!",
};
```

When using the "classic" `Object.freeze` method, we only freeze the root properties of an object:

```js
const frozen = Object.freeze(myObj);

frozen.rootProp2 = "?"; // error --> OK
delete frozen.rootProp1; // error --> OK
frozen.extraRootProp = "how are you?"; // error --> OK
frozen.rootProp1.leafProp1 = "hi"; // NO ERROR --> I don't want this
```

In order to deep freeze the object, we can use a method like [this one](https://github.com/substack/deep-freeze/blob/master/index.js):

```js
const deepFrozen = deepFreeze(myObj);

deepFrozen.rootProp1.leafProp1 = "hi"; // error --> OK
myObj.rootProp2 = "?"; // ERROR --> I don't want this
```

But that's still a problem for me: I would like a function that can return the frozen version of an object, **without freezing the original one** (I'm trying to learn functional programming so I want as less mutations as possible). How to do that?

Answer (score 0):

In ECMAScript 2018 (ES9), thanks to the [spread operator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Spread_syntax), it's possible to use this simple function:

```js
const deepFreeze = (obj) => typeof obj === "object"
    ? Object.freeze({
        ...Object.entries(obj).reduce(
          (prev, [key, value]) => ({
            ...prev,
            [key]: value ? deepFreeze(value) : value,
          }),
          {}
        ),
      })
    : typeof obj === "function" ? Object.freeze(obj) : obj;
```